# Why does this SQL-Statement lead to an error?

Tags: java, sql, phpmyadmin

I am getting quite angry with this, so I seek help from the crowd ;)

What I want to do: We have a Unity learning game which shall implement a login window. The entered credentials are then hashed (the pw is) and sent to the server, who then should check this against a database.

I have the following table:

xy.users_confirms with the following colums:

id  username    email   password    hashcode    created

Why does my code

```
String sql = "SELECT " + "xy.users_confirms.password as pwhash, "
                        +"FROM xy.users_confirms "  +"WHERE xy.users_confirms.username = " +"\"userNameToGetHashFor\"";
```

lead me to the SQLException "Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)"

?

Thanks, any input is much appreciated!

Comment: I wonder if  the comma after `pwhash,` and before `from` might cause it an issue.  Having said that, you should be using a `PreapredStatement`. See [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

Comment: Hi, sorry, the string sql is then prepared with PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
 String parameter = "'"+ strNameToGetHashFor + "'";
 String sql = "SELECT " + "xy.users_confirms.password as pwhash, "
             +"FROM xy.users_confirms "  
             +"WHERE xy.users_confirms.username ="+ parameter;
```

You are using `varchar` value as a parameter so it's need to be quot like this.`'username'`. or you can use [Stored Procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx).

Comment: Yep, true. It is defintely single quote. But still, even though the statement works inside phpMyAdmin, it does through Java.....

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would try getting a working query using the custom query box directly in phpmyadmin. Once you have a working query you can re-write it in java.

And I would try writing the syntax like this into the phpmyadmin query box:

```
SELECT password as pwhash
FROM xy.users_confirms
WHERE username ='userNameToGetHashFor'
```

Using the above syntax I don't see anyway your error could persist.

Phpmyadmin screen cap showing custom query box: http://screencast.com/t/9h8anH0Aj
(the 2 empty text boxes in screen cap are just me hiding my database info)

Comment: Hi Drew, you are right, at least in part. The phpMyAdmin request works, but when I copy it and use PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql); on the string I copied from the QueueBox of phpMyAdmin, error persists - unfortunately. :(

Comment: Hey @N30, yep this is what I expected actually and why I suggested testing first in phpmyadmin. On the bright side - now you know you're basic query structure is not the problem. That means you either have a problem with string concatenation or with the prepared statement in java.

Comment: For the next step I recommend 2 things: 1) check that your vars and your string is outputting in the same format as your working phpmyadmin query. (for example using  `System.out.println(sql);` or whatever). 2) verify that you can do ANY queries with your mysql prepared statement syntax. Try to output another query that's very simple (for example `"SELECT * FROM table`) and check that you can return ANY mysql results using the prepared statement format that you have.

Answer (score 1):

The comma after pwhash is one potential cause:

```
       + "xy.users_confirms.password as pwhash*!*,*!* "
```

Depending on the DBMS, you may also need to use single quotes instead of double quotes like this:

```
       + "'userNameToGetHashFor'";
```

Also this code is potentially vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack so you may want to make the userNameToGetHashFor a parameter rather than concatenating the string into the SQL statement.